# Debian 9 - install "xdebug master" instead of "Xdebug v2.7.0beta1"

Tags: php, laravel-5, xdebug, laravel-5.7, php-7.3

Please, on a Debian 9 : How to install **xdebug master** instead of **Xdebug v2.7.0beta1** ?

Because with **Laravel 5.7**, **Xdebug v2.7.0beta1** does not work with **PHP 7.3**.

Here one of Laravel's developers explains the problem : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27052

When I do : **apt-get install php7.3-xdebug**

With phpinfo() I see that it installed me **Xdebug v2.7.0beta1** instead of **PHP 7.3**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "master" package in the Debian repository. If you wish to install the `master`, you have to download [the sources](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug), compile then install by yourself.

You can refer to `Installation From Source` at https://xdebug.org/docs/install